# How to use the easypick plugin to choose date ranges?

Tags: javascript

I am using the [easepick](https://easepick.com/examples/hotel.html) Javascript plugin to generate a date range picker for reservation of a specific hotel room. It looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker"/>
<script>
  const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
  const bookedDates = [
      ['2023-04-19', '2023-04-21'],
      ['2023-04-28', '2023-04-29'],
      ['2023-04-29', '2023-04-30']
  ].map(d => {
      if (d instanceof Array) {
        const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD');

        return [start, end];
      }

      return new DateTime(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  });
  const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
      'https://easepick.com/css/demo_hotelcal.css',
    ],
    plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
    RangePlugin: {
      tooltipNumber(num) {
        return num - 1;
      },
      locale: {
        one: 'night',
        other: 'nights',
      },
    },
    LockPlugin: {
      minDate: new Date(),
      minDays: 2,
      inseparable: true,
      filter(date, picked) {
        if (picked.length === 0) {
          return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
        } else {
          const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
          return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
        }
      },
    },
    autoApply: false
  });
</script>
```

The code does almost what it is supposed to do. If you pick `2023-04-18` or any day before as your starting date it becomes possible to pick `2023-04-19` as your ending date. This makes sense, because while it should not be possible to choose someone elses reserved checkin date, it should be possible to choose it as checkout date.

My problem is with the subsequent dates. `2023-04-21` becomes displayed as reserved and all later date intervals move 1 day forward as well. This is only a cosmetic problem, because anything later than `2023-04-19` should be impossible to pick anyway. But it looks confusing. So how do I apply my filter only to the first reserved date that comes after my first pick? In this case it would mean changing the state of `2023-04-19` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this configuration: after selecting the starting date, it will disable and grey out the remaining days after the first day of the closest, already existing reservation.

```js
const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
const bookedDates = [
  ['2023-04-19', '2023-04-21'],
  ['2023-04-28', '2023-04-29'],
  ['2023-04-29', '2023-04-30']
].map(d => {
  if (d instanceof Array) {
    const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD');

    return [start, end];
  }

  return new DateTime(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
});
const picker = new easepick.create({
  element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  css: [
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
    'https://easepick.com/css/demo_hotelcal.css',
  ],
  plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
  RangePlugin: {
    tooltipNumber(num) {
      return num - 1;
    },
    locale: {
      one: 'night',
      other: 'nights',
    },
  },
  LockPlugin: {
    minDate: new Date(),
    minDays: 2,
    inseparable: true,
    filter(date, picked) {
      if (picked.length === 0) {
        return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
      } else {
        const prevBooked = bookedDates.find(([start]) => start.isBefore(picked[0]));
        const nextBooked = bookedDates.find(([start]) => start.isAfter(picked[0]));

        if (!nextBooked) {
          return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
        }

        const ms = nextBooked[0].getTime() + 86400000;
        const nextBookedDayAfter = new Date(ms);

        if (nextBooked && date.isSame(nextBooked[0], 'day')) {
          return false;
        }

        if (nextBooked && date.isSame(nextBookedDayAfter, 'day')) {
          return true;
        }
        if (prevBooked && date.isBetween(prevBooked[0], prevBooked[1], '()')) {
          return true;
        }

        if (nextBooked && date.isBetween(nextBooked[0], nextBooked[1], '()')) {
          return false;
        }

        if (bookedDates.filter(([start]) => date.isSame(start, 'day')).length > 0) {
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }
    },
  },

  autoApply: false,
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
 <input id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Looks very promising, however I identified two errors. Try choosing the very last date as your starting date. You'll see an error is raised. Also try picking a starting date from the next month and then move backwards. You'll see that it suddenly becomes possible to choose amongst the previously booked dates.